# Bind sum of integer from values of a map to text property

Tags: java, javafx, easybind

I got the following data model:

```
public class Player {
  // enum to integer (count)
  @Getter
  private MapProperty<ResourceType, Integer> resourceCards = new SimpleMapProperty<>();

  public void addResource(final ResourceType resourceType, final int amount) {
    this.resourceCards.get().put(resourceType, this.resourceCards.get().get(resourceType) + amount);
  }
}


public class Game {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private ObjectProperty<Player> currentPlayer = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

 }
```

Binding the map to a text property is quite easy:

```
final Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(EasyBind.select(game.getCurrentPlayer()).selectObject(player -> player.getResourceCards().asString()));
```

I would like to display the total amount of resource cards in the label.

Example:

Map: {Water=0, Gold=2, Lumber=5}

Label: 7

Map: {Water=0, Gold=0, Lumber=0}

Label: 0

How can I achieve this with JavaFX Bindings or/and [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MapProperty<S, T>` can be used as `ObservableMap<S, T>` and gets notified of changes of the wrapped map. This means you can use `Bindings.createStringBinding` on the map:

```
label.textProperty().bind(EasyBind.select(game.getCurrentPlayer())
                                  .selectObject(player -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> Integer.toString(player.getResourceCards().values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()),
                                                                                       player.getResourceCards())
                                  .orElse("0")));
```

**Note:** Convention for the method name of the method returning the property object itself is using `<propertyName>Property`. In case of your `Game`'s `currentPlayer` property this would be `currentPlayerProperty()` instead of `getCurrentPlayer()` and `resourceCardsProperty()` instead of `getResourceCards()`. I used the method names including `get` in the above code.

Furthermore using a `MapProperty` is unnecessary unless you're planing to replace the whole map instead of simply modifying the `Map`'s contents. You could simply use a readonly property of type `ObservableMap` in this case.